# Best way to handle a lottery draw?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `tickets` that store all tickets purchased. It looks like:

```
id      int    AI,primary
userid  int
```

Now, a user can obviously purchase as many tickets as they want to increase their odds of winning. Now is there anything wrong with just running this statement

```
SELECT
    u.id AS winner FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user = u.id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Is the MySQL function "truly" random enough for a system like this?

It seems like sometimes when I run the query, the same person is selected a lot.

Comment: why do you use left join?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

`RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.`

Also note as your table gets large this query will become extremely expensive since it will have to sort every row in the table before returning.